Как идентифицировать устройство для Web Push, в случае если пользователь несколько раз одобрял/отменял подписку на уведомления?
Подключаю Web Push API к своему сайту, подписка будет доступна только авторизованным пользователям и будет доступна для всех устройств с которых пользователь подписался на уведомления. Когда пользователь подписывается на уведомление, данные о подписке сохраняются в БД.
Допустим пользователь несколько раз разрешает/отменяет подписку в браузере(это можно делать и офлайн) с одного устройства. Как в данном случае идентифицировать устройство, что бы знать что делать в БД: обновить существующую или добавить новую подписку? Как идентифицировать устройство, какие практики используются?
На ум приходят несколько решений:
1. Парсить UserAgent в строку и сохранять хэш вместе с подпиской, например:


getHash(os_name + os_version + browser_name + (device_model ?? ''));



2. Генерировать случайный уникальный для данного пользователя хэш и хранить его local storage или IndexedDB, а также сохранять хэш вместе с подпиской
3. Ничего не делать и хранить все подписки в том числе и мёртвые. И делая очередную рассылку по подпискам пользователя: удалять на основе ответов от сервиса рассылок(404, 410)
Что посоветуете?

как именно отключается подписка? Разве при этом сервер не получает оповещение?

@Grundy уведомления от сайта можно отключить и офлайн, зайдя в настройки браузера, в таком случае ни о каких уведомлениях не может идти речь.

при появлении сети всегда можно проверить подключены уведомления или нет

@Grundy допустим..., теперь он заходит на сайт снова(после отписки) и на клиенте видно, что уведомления отключены на данном устройстве, как мне определить: он отключил подписку на "старом" устройстве или зашёл с нового устройства, где уведомления ещё не подключены? Про это мой вопрос...

так если устройство старое - ты пишешь что у тебя есть запись в бд

@Grundy "так если устройство старое" в этом и вопрос, как это определить?! 1 и 2 решение приведённое мною пытаются это решить

как ты осуществляешь подписку?

@Grundy в общих чертах: 1 Пользователь жмёт на кнопку подписаться; 2 Клиент проверяет такую возможность, и в случае успеха отправляет данные подписки на сервер; 3 Сервер сохраняет данные подписки связывая её с данным пользователем; ps для одного пользователя может быть несколько подписок с разных устройств

добавь пример кода в вопрос

@Grundy во первых это большой объём кода, разбросанный клиент/сервер по разным функциям; во вторых у меня нет проблем с кодом; в третьих вопрос концептуальный, какое решение выбрать, приведённое мною(1, 2, 3) или кто-то предложит своё

Для ответа необходим существующий код, чтобы видеть какие данные у тебя есть в данный момент. Весь код добавлять не нужно, достаточно добавить [mcve]
